# Compiling frames into a video with ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook

I have a folder with a number of frames in which I'd like to concatenate into an mp4 file using ffmpeg. What is the correct syntax to do this in a Jupyter notebook script? I have tried:

```
os.system("ffmpeg -r 30 -i ./inputs/upload%00001d.png -y ./inputs/result.mp4")
```

The above runs through with no errors but does not produce an output.

Comment: maybe you meant to specify `upload%05d.png` as the file format? can you give me some examples of the full file names?

Comment: So the images are the result of a previous deconstruction of a video into individual frames which saved the frames as images called "upload00001.png", "upload00002.png", ..., "upload00233.png"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've stated in the comment, correct your file format to `upload%05d.png` and consider specifying the codec too:

```py
def saveMpeg():
    os.system("ffmpeg -r 30 -i ./inputs/upload%05d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -y ./inputs/result.mp4")

saveMpeg()
```